# How to encode high dimensional dynamic categorical features

Tags: feature-selection, categorical-encoding

Example: Facebook newsfeed ranking. This is typically done by relevance scoring each post using a regression model based on a number of features.

Typical features might include information from the profile of the user, e.g. numerical features such as age, signup timestamp as well as categorial features such as their interests, friends, pages followed, etc. How would I best encode these categorical features for training a neural network?

One-hot encoding the friends list would result in a 2 billion dimensional vector(one for each facebook user). Not only is this way too large but the number of users changes constantly so I would have to constantly retrain the model whenever a new user signs up.

So, how do they do it?

Comment: don't believe a 2 billion dimensional vector is so bad.you use sparse matrices so you don't store zeros in training data. feature embeddings are used. see description of youtube algorithm https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45530.pdf

Comment: [tag:embeddings]

Comment: Ok, this paper confirms they use embeddings for high dimensional features for youtube. What about the output labels though? According to the paper: "The softmax
layer outputs a multinomial distribution over the same 1M
video classes with a dimension of 256 (which can be thought
of as a separate output video embedding)." What does that mean? Is the output a 1M dimensional one-hot encoding or a 256 dimensional embedding?